# How to remove last character with slash in unix?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a vlsi code like this.

```
instance1/instance2/instance3/and_gate_inst/and_gate/a_pin
instance1/instance2/or_gate/b_pin
```

Now can you help me to get something like below:

```
instance1/instance2/instance3/and_gate_inst/and_gate 
instance1/instance2/or_gate
```

Sorry for the confusion, above is the right question...

Comment: (-1) because I had to completely re-write the question, based on a comment on a deleted answer. (you should have updated the question as asked, clear questions are better than pages of comments. And comments can disappear.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's|/[^/]*$||'
```

Where

- `/` matches literal `/`
- `[^/]*` matches zero or more non-`/` characters
- `$` matches the end of the line

Answer (score 6):

It seems you want to get paths to directories that contain the files whose paths are stored in those lines.

Answers that cover the basic cases have already been given, however I'll mention a few points worth considering in the general case:

- on most Unices, file paths can be made of any sequence of  bytes other than 0. That includes the byte used to represent the newline character. That can include sequence of bytes that don't form valid character, that can be longer than `LINE_MAX` (the standard constant (but whose value is left at the discretion of each implementation) that defines the maximum number of bytes text lines may have if you want to be guaranteed that text utilities will work properly on them).

  So here that input format cannot express any list of file paths (like the ones that contain newline characters), and even for a list of file paths without newline characters and under LINE_MAX bytes, you'd need to run  text utilities in the C locale to be sure they can cope with arbitrary byte values.
- `/` is the path component separator, but

  - `/` alone is special and represents the root directory file. There is no *directory* that contains that file, though by convention we generally say its parent directory is itself. In any case, you'll like have to treat it specially if it may occur in the input.
  - sequences of more than one `/` act like one, `foo//bar` is the same as `foo/bar`.
  - except at the start for a sequence of exactly two `//`. Where `///foo` is the same as `/foo`, but `//foo` is not guaranteed to be the same as `/foo` (and on some systems it isn't). More generally, there's not much we can tell in the general case of files that start with `//`. For instance, each `/` delimited component may not even be *directories*, so in this case, it's hard decide what to do.
- `foo` is also a relative path. Its parent directory is `.` not *the empty string*.
- `.` and `..` are more directory traversing tools than actual files. But they *refer* to actual files. So, what should we report for their  dirname or parent directory (`..` and `../..` respectively? Or `.` like for other `/`-less relative paths?).
- `foo/bar/` or `foo/bar//` are the ame as `foo/bar` at least as long as `foo/bar` itself is a directory, so its parent directory should be `foo`.

A less *tamed* input could be:

```
//foo/bar
///foo//bar//
foo
foo//
.
../
foo<0x80>bar/baz<0x81>
--foo
/
//
///
```

One way to address the problems would be  to defer to the `dirname` command, which is meant for that and accept its decision when there's no single obvious one.

The difficult part portably is to get from that line-based input to arguments to `dirname`.

On a GNU system, that can be done with:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a your-file dirname --
```

Which with GNU `dirname` 8.30 gives:

```
//foo
///foo
.
.
.
.
foo<0x80>bar
.
/
/
/
```

But won't work on most other systems as:

- `-d`, `-r` and `-a` or non-standard GNU `xargs` extension
- several `xargs` implementations choke on non-text input
- `dirname` is not required to accept more than one argument (and few do).

It could still fail for file paths that are longer than the maximum size arguments to executed commands.

Comment: I just moved a comment on a deleted answer, that explains the question. It is not about Unix directories, as I had also thought. (+1 for the great answer, to the question as it was written, and for the time you spent on it)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, this is one of those great reference answers such as "Why is using a shell loop to process text bad?", but unfortunately I think it won't get the deserved attention in this particular question. Because of that  I think it is worth moving it to a more general question (if it is possible or viable).

Comment: @Quasimodo if you write a question for it, and stéphane copies answer to it, then drop a comment with a link here. (so I can upvote it).

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired output with `awk` then you can use the following command:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $1"/"$2}' <file_name>
```

The `-F'/'` option defines "/" as the column delimiter.
The print $1"/"$2, prints first column, concatenates "/" and prints the second column.

You can also achieve your desired output with cut.

```
cut -d'/' -f1,2 <file_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hierarchical net names are stored one per line in a file named netnames.txt,we can run the following `tcl` code to get the gate connected to that net.

```
tclsh - netnames.txt <<\_TCL_
set fh [open [lindex $argv 1]]
while { [gets $fh line] >= 0 } {
puts [join [lreplace [split $line /] end end] /]
}
close $fh
_TCL_
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all Guys,

Finally this worked.

```
awk -F "/" '{$NF=""; print $0}' instance1/instance2/instance3/and_gate_inst/and_gate/a_pin | sed 's/ /\//g' | sed 's/\/$//'
awk -F "/" '{$NF=""; print $0}' instance1/instance2/or_gate/b_pin | sed 's/ /\//g' | sed 's/\/$//'
```

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk and you certainly don't need 2 seds with 2 pipes. Also that whole command line makes no sense. The awk will remove the substring after the last `/` then replace every `/` with a blank then the first sed will re-replace the first blank that the awk had added with `/` then the second sed will re-remove the `/` added by the previous sed if the previous sed had added it because that was the only `/` on the original input processed by awk. Complete nonsense.

Comment: Hi Ed Morton,
Thanks for your comments, I am a newbie.
I have to learn in awk and sed more. But, meanwhile, can you suggest me a best option.

Comment: The sed answer you accepted seems fine.